# Can I declare globals to Flow in the same file?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is it possible to declare a global variable in the same file, and then analyze only this file? Similar like using eslint or jshint. Use-case would be adding jQuery, `$`, as an object with whatever properties.

Something like:

```js
// @declare var $: object
let foo = $('.foo-elements');
```

Like in this link, but on the fly: https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/#toc-declaring-a-global-variable

```js
declare var PI: number;
```

I'm not using Babel, so the code has to be ES8 JS, browser-ready.

The documentation mentions inline declarations, but they are not JS and must be transpiled to work, it seems: https://flow.org/en/docs/declarations/#toc-inlining-declarations-in-regular-code

Comment: "Is it possible?" What happens when you try?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Well, with which syntax should I try? :D

Comment: I think you should edit your question to make it more clear what you are asking. "What is the syntax to do..." is a different question than "Is it possible...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to declare a global variable using flow so that you do not get flow errors. But you do not use babel or and transpiler so it must run without tooling.

I think comment syntax is what you're looking for
https://flow.org/en/docs/types/comments/

```
// @flow

/*::
declare var $: {
  (...args: Array<any>): any;
  [key: string]: () => any,
  ...
},
*/

let foo = $('.foo-elements');
```

Taken the liberty to also add the most basic implementation for `$` object

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks! Incidentally, do you know why Flow does not support reading standard JSDoc comments?

Comment: It didn't used to but it does as of version [0.133.0](https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.133.0)

Comment: Cool, but it cannot be used as an alternative to transpiling Flow syntax? Maybe I'll open a new question for this.

Comment: Maybe we're talking about two separate things here. One is JSDocs which you can see here https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/core.js#L41. The other is comment syntax which is how you define flow types without transpiling. They're different things and serve different purposes. If this is about comment syntax you can ask here, otherwise yes I think a new question is appropriate.

Comment: This question kind of answers my own: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46158469/include-flow-types-into-jsdoc