# Can I use JSDoc annotations with Flow to enforce typing on a per-file basis?

Tags: flowtype

What I want is to Flow to understand JSDoc syntax, without any transpiling.

Example:

```js
// @flow
/**
 * @param {string} str
 * @return {string}
 */
function foo(str) {
  return str + str;
}
foo(1);  // Flow shows error
```

And then using `flow check-contents < foo.js` to get the error.

Possible somehow? Preferably without using Babel or any other transpiler. (And more importantly - why would Flow choose to invent its own syntax when there's already a standard available? This will basically force us to choose TypeScript over Flow.)

Related question: [Include Flow Types into JSDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46158469/include-flow-types-into-jsdoc)

Comment: Actually Typescript supports type checking javascript files with JSDoc annotations https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#param-and-returns

Comment: @Aleksey L. thank you. Yes, I think we'll have to choose TypeScript instead.

Comment: Nowadays it is not really hard decision 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can use inline type declarations like described here: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/comments/

Example:

```js
// @flow

/*::
type MyAlias = {
  foo: number,
  bar: boolean,
  baz: string,
};
*/

function method(value /*: MyAlias */) /*: boolean */ {
  return value.bar;
}

method({ foo: 1, bar: true, baz: ["oops"] });
```